# How to re-index a subtask through script listeners?

Tags: groovy, jira

I need to re-index a subtask everytime I create it.
Thus I would like to use script listeners.

How do I do this?

Thank. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, for reindex you can use code like this

for JIRA7

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor;
import com.atlassian.jira.util.ImportUtils;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.index.IssueIndexingService;
def issueManager = ComponentAccessor.getIssueManager();
def issueIndexingService = ComponentAccessor.getComponent(IssueIndexingService);
def wasIndexing = ImportUtils.isIndexIssues();
ImportUtils.setIndexIssues(true);
issueIndexingService.reIndex(issueManager.getIssueObject(issue.id));
ImportUtils.setIndexIssues(wasIndexing);
```

or for JIRA6

```
import com.atlassian.jira.util.ImportUtils;
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor;
def wasIndexing = ImportUtils.isIndexIssues();
ImportUtils.setIndexIssues(true);
ComponentAccessor.getIssueIndexManager().reIndex(issue);
ImportUtils.setIndexIssues(wasIndexing);
```

But what you point to this action? Subtask anyway reindex itself on create step and reindex from listener is not nessesary.

Comment: Hi @sintasy,
I have a create issue listener to modify a parent field every time a subtask is created. When the subtask is created, it is not able to get the parent object immedeailty after creation, so I figured indexing the issue might get the job done.

My Jira version is 6.4, thus IssueIndexingService doesn't work, what can I use instead of that.

Thanks.

Comment: I've update first answer for jira6.
But you can move script after first step(Creates the issue originally.). And then you can recieve issue.getParentObject()
As I know script listener have greater affect performance than if you just do it in create step. And anyway, remember that issue won't create before you listener code won't complete(If you don't start new thread from listener of course).

Comment: Hi @sintasy, I probably misdirected you.
Here's whats happening:
 I create a subtask manually, it fires an issue created event. Now there's a listener which gets started on issue created event, this listener updates a parent field.
 When I do a issue.getParentObject, the parent object is null probably because the listener is being called even before link is created between subtask and parent. Can you advise me on how to address this issue?
Thanks.

Comment: Go to workflow, then go to first step who called Create(1), you can found it near you first workflow status. Then add a scripted postfunction, then move this postfunction under "Create the issue originally" step. Then you can access to parent issue from this postfunction(this code will be run after subtask created) and manipulate with parrent issue fields. Also if you have one workflow for all issuetypes in project you need add "if" condition to issue type in scripted postfunction.